# R group variables in days calculated from interval between start and end time

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe as below

```
tmpdf <- data.frame(licensePlate = c("Y80901", "Y80901", "Y80901", "AMG-999", "AMG-999", "W3188", "W3188"),  
starttime= c("2015-09-18 09:55", "2015-09-18 23:00", "2015-09-20 15:00", "2015-09-17 15:42", "2015-09-21 09:22", "2015-09-17 09:00", "2015-09-21 14:00"),
endtime = c("2015-09-18 17:55", "2015-09-20 11:00", "2015-09-21 12:00",  "2015-09-18 13:00",  "2015-09-21 14:22", "2015-09-21 12:00", "2015-09-21 16:00"))
    tmpdf
      licensePlate        starttime          endtime
    1       Y80901 2015-09-18 09:55 2015-09-18 17:55
    2       Y80901 2015-09-18 23:00 2015-09-20 11:00
    3       Y80901 2015-09-20 15:00 2015-09-21 12:00
    4      AMG-999 2015-09-17 15:42 2015-09-18 13:00
    5      AMG-999 2015-09-21 09:22 2015-09-21 14:22
    6        W3188 2015-09-17 09:00 2015-09-21 12:00
    7        W3188 2015-09-21 14:00 2015-09-21 16:00
```

I want to count the last n days (for example, last 5 days from 9/17 to 9/21) in time used per day of each licensePlate, My expected result is as below:

```
   Period            LicensePlate        Used Time   

1 2015-09-17         Y80901              0
2 2015-09-17         AMG-999             8.3     
3 2015-09-17         W3188               15
4 2015-09-18         Y80901              9
5 2015-09-18         AMG-999             13
6 2015-09-18         W3188               24
7 2015-09-19         Y80901              24
8 2015-09-19         AMG-999             0
9 2015-09-19         W3188               24
10 2015-09-20        Y80901              20
11 2015-09-20        AMG-999             0
12 2015-09-20        W3188               24
13 2015-09-21        Y80901              12
14 2015-09-21        AMG-999             5
15 2015-09-21        W3188               14
```

I think dplyr/data.table and lubridate can be used to obtain my result,
and I may need to measure time period in days, but I don't know how to cut
within a start/end interval when start/end will differ per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. This is *almost* your desired output, as it doesn't show you the missing `licensePlate` per period.

The first step would be to convert your date to valid `POSIXct` class, then expand the data to a per minute level (probably the most costly part in this solution) and the aggregate by `licensePlate` and by `Period` while summing up the results (I'm not using `as.Date` here because it handles badly `POSIX` values with values between 00 and 1 am).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tmpdf)[, `:=`(starttime = as.POSIXct(starttime), endtime = as.POSIXct(endtime))]
res <- tmpdf[, .(licensePlate, Period = seq(starttime, endtime, by = "1 min")), by = 1:nrow(tmpdf)]
res[, .(Used_Time = round(.N/60L, 1L)), keyby = .(Period = substr(Period, 1L, 10L), licensePlate)]
#         Period licensePlate Used_Time
#  1: 2015-09-17      AMG-999       8.3
#  2: 2015-09-17        W3188      15.0
#  3: 2015-09-18      AMG-999      13.0
#  4: 2015-09-18        W3188      24.0
#  5: 2015-09-18       Y80901       9.0
#  6: 2015-09-19        W3188      24.0
#  7: 2015-09-19       Y80901      24.0
#  8: 2015-09-20        W3188      24.0
#  9: 2015-09-20       Y80901      20.0
# 10: 2015-09-21      AMG-999       5.0
# 11: 2015-09-21        W3188      14.0
# 12: 2015-09-21       Y80901      12.0
```

Comment: Thanks, awesome example of data.table, just a few line code resolved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Take a deep breath. Here is my solution

## Initializing Data

```
tmpdf <- data.frame(licensePlate = c("Y80901", "Y80901", "Y80901", "AMG-999", "AMG-999", "W3188", "W3188"),  
                starttime= c("2015-09-18 09:55", "2015-09-18 23:00", "2015-09-20 15:00", "2015-09-17 15:42", "2015-09-21 09:22", "2015-09-17 09:00", "2015-09-21 14:00"),
                endtime = c("2015-09-18 17:55", "2015-09-20 11:00", "2015-09-21 12:00",  "2015-09-18 13:00",  "2015-09-21 14:22", "2015-09-21 12:00", "2015-09-21 16:00"))

'converting to POSIXct for better date/time handling'
    tmpdf$starttime <- as.POSIXct(tmpdf$starttime, tz = "GMT")
    tmpdf$endtime <- as.POSIXct(tmpdf$endtime, tz = "GMT")
```

## Data Preparation

To perform the required operations your complete usage data has to be converted to daily usage data. So I have written the following function to prepare the data into a required format.

```
#splits single usage data into two  
splitToTwo <- function(list){
newList <- NULL

for ( i in 1:nrow(list)){

 tmp <- list[i,]

 # set the end time of the first split as 23:59:59
 list[i,]$endtime <- as.Date(list[i,]$starttime) + hours(23) + minutes(59) + seconds(59)

 # set the start time of the second split as 00:00:01
 tmp$starttime <- list[i,]$endtime + seconds(2)

 # add the new df to the list  
 tmp <-  rbind(tmp,list[i,])
 newList <- rbind(newList,tmp)
 }
 return(newList)
}


#recursive function. Split the usage data into two till there are completely normalised to daily usage data
setDailyUsage <- function(tmpdf){

  # create a exclusive subset where the usage spawns more than a day   
  list <- tmpdf[as.Date(tmpdf$endtime) - as.Date(tmpdf$starttime) > 0,   ]

  # replace tmpdf with usage that started and ended the same day   
  tmpdf <- tmpdf[ as.Date(tmpdf$endtime) - as.Date(tmpdf$starttime) == 0,]  

  # call to our split function to split the dataset with usage spawning more than one day  
  split <- splitToTwo(list)

  # add the now split data to our exclusive
  tmpdf <- rbind(tmpdf,split)

  if (nrow(tmpdf[as.Date(tmpdf$endtime) - as.Date(tmpdf$starttime) > 0,   ])>0){
      tmpdf <- setDailyUsage(tmpdf)
  }

return(tmpdf)

}
```

## Prepared Data

Our prepared data

```
preparedData <- setDailyUsage(tmpdf)
    licensePlate           starttime             endtime
1         Y80901 2015-09-18 09:55:00 2015-09-18 17:55:00
5        AMG-999 2015-09-21 09:22:00 2015-09-21 14:22:00
7          W3188 2015-09-21 14:00:00 2015-09-21 16:00:00
21        Y80901 2015-09-18 23:00:00 2015-09-18 23:59:59
3         Y80901 2015-09-21 00:00:01 2015-09-21 12:00:00
31        Y80901 2015-09-20 15:00:00 2015-09-20 23:59:59
4        AMG-999 2015-09-18 00:00:01 2015-09-18 13:00:00
41       AMG-999 2015-09-17 15:42:00 2015-09-17 23:59:59
61         W3188 2015-09-17 09:00:00 2015-09-17 23:59:59
2         Y80901 2015-09-20 00:00:01 2015-09-20 11:00:00
211       Y80901 2015-09-19 00:00:01 2015-09-19 23:59:59
611        W3188 2015-09-18 00:00:01 2015-09-18 23:59:59
612        W3188 2015-09-19 00:00:01 2015-09-19 23:59:59
6          W3188 2015-09-21 00:00:01 2015-09-21 12:00:00
613        W3188 2015-09-20 00:00:01 2015-09-20 23:59:59
```

## Data Manipulation

Now we create a new DF which represents the data in the required format. This will initially have empty values in the UsedTime column.

```
preparedData$duration <- preparedData$endtime - preparedData$starttime
noOfUniquePlates <- length(unique(preparedData$licensePlate))
Period <- rep(seq(from=(min(as.Date(preparedData$starttime))),to=(max(as.Date(preparedData$starttime))), by="day"),noOfUniquePlates)
noOfUniqueDays <- length(unique(Period))
LicensePlate <- rep(unique(preparedData$licensePlate),each=noOfUniqueDays)
UsedTime <- 0

newDF <- data.frame(Period,LicensePlate,UsedTime)
```

Now a simply mapply function on each row of the newDF , searching for the right usage data in preparedData df.

```
findUsage <- function(p,l){
  sum(preparedData[as.Date(preparedData$starttime) == p & as.Date(preparedData$endtime) == p & preparedData$licensePlate == l ,  ]$duration)
}
newDF$UsedTime <- mapply( findUsage, newDF$Period, newDF$LicensePlate)
newDF$UsedTime <- newDF$UsedTime/60

    > newDF[with(newDF,order(Period)),]
       Period LicensePlate  UsedTime
1  2015-09-17       Y80901  0.000000
6  2015-09-17      AMG-999  8.299722
11 2015-09-17        W3188 14.999722
2  2015-09-18       Y80901  8.999722
7  2015-09-18      AMG-999 12.999722
12 2015-09-18        W3188 23.999444
3  2015-09-19       Y80901 23.999444
8  2015-09-19      AMG-999  0.000000
13 2015-09-19        W3188 23.999444
4  2015-09-20       Y80901 19.999444
9  2015-09-20      AMG-999  0.000000
14 2015-09-20        W3188 23.999444
5  2015-09-21       Y80901 11.999722
10 2015-09-21      AMG-999  5.000000
15 2015-09-21        W3188 13.999722
```

I had to limit explanations to keep the answer short. Let me know if you need any clarification in comments.

Comment: thanks for the details and your sol works as expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that plyr can be used to solve this problem. One possible solution:

```
tmpdf$starttime <- as.POSIXct(tmpdf$starttime) #convert date/time columns to date/time values in R
tmpdf$endtime <- as.POSIXct(tmpdf$endtime) #convert date/time columns to date/time values in R
newdf <- ddply(tmpdf,.(as.Date(starttime),licensePlate),function(df){
df$diffdays <- as.double(difftime(df$endtime,df$starttime,units='days'))
df
})
#If you want to only have the Period, LicensePlate, and Used Time columns remaining:
newdf <- subset(newdf,select=c(1,2,5))
colnames(newdf) <- c('Period','LicensePlate','UsedTime')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks,  but your solution only obtain the "diffdays" of each row, what I want is to obtained the result per days(not total diffdays), as highlight in my expect result.

Answer (score 0):

try this- does it help

```
`tmpdf <- data.frame(licensePlate = c("Y80901", "Y80901", "Y80901", "AMG-999", "AMG-999", "W3188", "W3188"),  
                    starttime= c("2015-09-18 09:55", "2015-09-18 23:00", "2015-09-20 15:00", "2015-09-17 15:42", "2015-09-21 09:22", "2015-09-17 09:00", "2015-09-21 14:00"),
                    endtime = c("2015-09-18 17:55", "2015-09-20 11:00", "2015-09-21 12:00",  "2015-09-18 13:00",  "2015-09-21 14:22", "2015-09-21 12:00", "2015-09-21 16:00"))

tmpdf
str(tmpdf)
library(lubridate)
tmpdf$starttime=ymd_hm(paste(tmpdf$starttime))
tmpdf$endtime=ymd_hm(paste(tmpdf$endtime))
tmpdf$Period=day(tmpdf$starttime)
tmpdf$diff=difftime(tmpdf$endtime,tmpdf$starttime)
tmpdf`
```

[image]

Comment: You can put the results themselves in the answer... this is preferred to an image of them, generally.

Comment: i did it but the nice column /table format went awry.

Comment: @Ajay, thanks, somehow, I am not asking to get the difftime of each  Start/end time record, I want to summary the result per days as mentioned in my "expect result".